# Displaying Validate errors to users using Spring, WebFlow, Dojo and Dijit

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow

I am working on a Spring WebFlow project that is using Dojo (dijit) for the forms and if the user does now fill in a textfield that is required the field does turn red on the click of the submit button. But radio buttons and checkboxes dont..

1) How can I make a radio button and checkbox act like text fields and turn red?

2) How can I change the following code popup a messages that the user has to fix some text fields.

```
<input type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" id="submit" value="Submit"  tabindex="11" />
<script type="text/javascript">
            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({
                elementId : 'submit',
                event : 'onclick'
            }));
        </script>
```

Comment: for 1) I guess you could use the `validate` function of your radiobutton and checkbox to change the color via javascript.

Comment: thanks rptmat57 but you know I am not going to understand how to do it yet.  looking for examples.

Comment: actually, 1) might not be possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons

Comment: thanks.. how about the other question..  #2  Making a popup if any fields dont pass the checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 2) you can use `Spring.validateAll()` instead of the ValidateAllDecoration. (you have to remove the ValidateAllDecoration)

the function `Spring.validateAll()` return true or false depending on the validation results.

something like that on the onClick:

```
onclick="if(!Spring.validateAll()){alert('errors')}else{Spring.submitForm(...)}"
```

should work