# How to change the color of a standard radio button?

Tags: html

Coding a simple radio button generates a blue button

```
 <input type="radio" name="sample" />
 <input type="radio" name="sample" />
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/XytJC/2/

How can I make these red?

Thanks

Comment: You can't, unfortunately.

Comment: You can't*. It will display using the device/browser UI styles.


* Well you can with something like http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/ but it's better to stick with the defaults, in terms of accessibility etc. Note - this doesn't actually affect the radio button styling, it just hides the radio button and adds a clickable label over the top.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I change the color of radio buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons). You need JS and/or custom images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it's impossible to make it appear in the same way across the all available browsers because of not fully supported CSS3 and HTML5. So what I suggest you, is to use a plugin **[Uniform.js](http://uniformjs.com/)** to get what you are looking for.

But if you are asking this question, I would mention also, that you will need to achieve this by using the css sprite method. Here on **[This website](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)** you will find the corresponding documention of "how to..."

Answer (score 0):

Try using a span, as explained [here](http://www.andreapinchi.it/how-to-style-radio-buttons-with-pure-css/).