# Set background to radio button when active

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

This is the default style when my radio button active: [image]

and this is what I want when active : [image]

Any idea to do that in CSS?

Comment: You have the change the entire element. You can't just change the background color.

Comment: http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ ... 2 sec of looking for it on Google. If you spend some time searching, you may find what you need

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23167637/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-selected-radio-buttons-center-circle

Answer (score 0):

To work with custom styled form elements I can recommend using [uniform](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform).
Although it requires some jquery, once setup it works pretty smooth for all form elements.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').uniform();
```

Custom CSS

```
input[type="radio"] { visibility: hidden; }
.radio span {
    background-image: url(http://path-to-unchecked.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.radio span.checked { background-image: url(http://path-to-checked.png); }
```

The script will wrap some extra HTML around all targeted fields. This will be the same requirement if you want a CSS only solution.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/b6Lg31mr/)**