# how to set a colour for input type radio html?

Tags: css, html

how to set a colour for input type radio in  html without using CSS, is it possible to make something like:

```
   <input type="radio" color"red"></input>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use CSS? Its meant for it. Many attribute properties are deprecated in HTML5

Comment: What colour are you trying to set, exactly? And `<input>` doesn't have a closing (`</input>`) tag, it's a void element, it can't have any content so it self-closes: `<input />`.

Comment: Well, in HTML5, there is no self-closing tag anymore, just `<input ....>`

Comment: @Mike: there was never a closing tag for the `<input>` element, it's *always* been a void element.

Comment: Correct; however there is no `/` in HTML5. The `/` was part of XHTML, if I remember correctly.

Comment: is your problem the same with this? <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons>

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" style="color:red;"/>
```

Like this but it is not recommanded. Listen to those comments and include the css in a separate file.

Comment: Strictly speaking, though, that's just a less-efficient means of using CSS (though admittedly CSS is the only valid way to go to 'solve' this 'problem').