# Changing the style of widgets

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know how to change the style of "radioButton" and "checkboxInput" widgets with css (tag$style() ).

Any help is appreciated! 
Thank you!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  h3("Hi! I would like to know how to change the style of these widgets with css (tag$style)"),
  h3("I can change the style of sliders, unfortunately I cannot figure out how to do this with 'radioButtons'
     and 'checkboxInput'. I usually inspect HTML-element in my browser and look for the css style, in this case this strategy does not work."),
  br(),
  br(),
  radioButtons(inputId = "ex_radio", label = "How to change my style?",
               choices = c("I want to be red when checked", "I want to be green")),
  br(),
  br(),

  checkboxInput(inputId = "ex_checkbox", label = "I'd like to look bit different as well",
                value = TRUE),

  br(),
  br(),
  h3("Any help is appreciated :) Thank you!")
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) { })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text you want to change is in a `<span>`. You can select the first `span` after the radio input by using the `element+element` CSS selector:

```
tags$style("input[type='radio']:checked+span{ 
             color: red; 
             }
input[type='radio']+span{ 
   color: green; 
}")
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) for more details. If you have more than one radio button elements, you can specifically apply this CSS to one of them using the `#id` selector, for ex:

```
#ex_radio input[type='radio']:checked+span{ 
             color: red; 
             }
```

For the checkboxes, you can do the same thing by replacing `type='radio'` by `type=checkbox`.

Comment: Thank you for  a very fast answer! :) 
Is there any way to change the blue colour of the buttons?  (not labels)

Comment: To change the color, you can look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons), not sure it can be easily done with css though.