# How change the color of the radio button

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the background-color of a radio button by CSS ?
I looked on the internet but I only find solutions in JS and I do not understand them necessarily. I tried this but it doesn't work :

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sound-signal">
  Signal sonore :
  <input type="radio" name="soundsignal" id="soundsignal" checked="checked">
  <label for="soundsignal">Oui</label>
  <input type="radio" name="soundsignal">
  <label for="soundsignal">Non</label>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a duplicate question. Look here for answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4253939/4342197

Comment: reopen answer please.

Comment: @ehsan — It's a duplicate question, so: No. If you can give a better answer, then give it on the original question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways to style radio buttons (and checkboxes by the way) only with CSS:

- via styling label's pseudoselector and hiding radio buttons

  ```css
  /* completely hiding radio button */
  input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
  }

  /* simulate radiobutton appearance using pseudoselector */
  input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    content: "";
    /* create custom radiobutton appearance */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    /* background-color only for content */
    background-clip: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    background-color: #e7e6e7;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  /* appearance of checked radiobutton */
  input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    background-color: red;
  }

  /* resetting default box-sizing */
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  /* optional styles for centering radiobuttons */
  .sound-signal label {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="sound-signal">
    Signal sonore:
    <input type="radio" name="soundsignal" id="soundsignal1" checked="checked">
    <label for="soundsignal1">Oui</label>
    <input type="radio" name="soundsignal" id="soundsignal2">
    <label for="soundsignal2">Non</label>
  </div>
  ```
- via hiding standard appearance using CSS `appearance: none` and applying custom appearance. Unfortunately this way doesn't work in IE.

  ```css
  input[type="radio"] {
    /* remove standard background appearance */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    /* create custom radiobutton appearance */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 3px;
    /* background-color only for content */
    background-clip: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    background-color: #e7e6e7;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  /* appearance for checked radiobutton */
  input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background-color: red;
  }

  /* optional styles for centering radiobuttons */
  .sound-signal {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="sound-signal">
    Signal sonore :
    <input type="radio" name="soundsignal" id="soundsignal1" checked="checked">
    <label for="soundsignal1">Oui</label>
    <input type="radio" name="soundsignal" id="soundsignal2">
    <label for="soundsignal2">Non</label>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Option 1- works like charm. Cheers

Comment: @Ramya Glad to be helpful for you!

Comment: fast forwarding to 2021, this still helped me... ty

Comment: The second one works both on Edge and Safari.