# Styling Radio Button Breaks Functionality

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a Vue app with a HTML Form with multiple sets of radio buttons.

I customized their appearance using the SO answer [written here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327209/4330767)

However, when I click on any of the radio buttons, only the first set of radio buttons are affected, even when clicking a different set's radio button.

This is the html and css (JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/e76tcuxh/))

Any idea why this is happening?

**Update:** The problem was with the `label` tags - their `for` attribute was still set to the first set of radio buttons!

```
                            <div class="time_input" >
                              <div class="time_input__radio_group">
                                <div class="radio_group">
                                  <input type="radio" name="start" id="am" :value="true" v-model="startInMorning">
                                  <label class="radio_label" for="am">AM</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio_group">
                                  <input type="radio" name="start" id="pm" :value="false" v-model="startInMorning">
                                  <label class="radio_label" for="pm">PM</label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="days_open_input">
                              <div class="radio_group" >
                                <input type="radio" name="days_open" id="one_day" :value="1" v-model="days_open" checked>
                                <label class="radio_label" for="am">1</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="radio_group">
                                <input type="radio" name="days_open" id="two_days" :value="2" v-model="days_open">
                                <label class="radio_label" for="pm">2</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="radio_group">
                                <input type="radio" name="days_open" id="three_days" :value="3" v-model="days_open">
                                <label class="radio_label" for="pm">3</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tracks_limit_input">
                              <div class="radio_group">
                                <input type="radio" name="tracks_limit" id="eight_songs" value="8" v-model="tracks_limit" >
                                <label class="radio_label " for="am">8</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="radio_group">
                                <input type="radio" name="tracks_limit" id="sixteen_songs" value="16" v-model="tracks_limit" checked class="tracks_limit_input__margin">
                                <label class="radio_label" for="pm">16</label>
                              </div>
                            
                            </div>
```

```
/* completely hiding radio button */
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

/* simulate radiobutton appearance using pseudoselector */
input[type="radio"] + *::before {
  content: "";
  /* create custom radiobutton appearance */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* background-color only for content */
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  background-color: #e7e6e7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* appearance of checked radiobutton */
input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: black;
}

/* resetting default box-sizing */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* optional styles for centering radiobuttons */
.radio-group label {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with the HTML!

The `for` attribute on the `label` tags was set to the wrong radio buttons

ie

```
<input type="radio" name="days_open" id="two_days" :value="2" v-model="days_open">
                                <label class="radio_label" for="pm">2</label>
<input type="radio" name="days_open" id="two_days" :value="2" v-model="days_open">
                                <label class="radio_label" for="pm">2</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no mistake with the `css`

The code you are using for the HTML is the one causes problem:

1st it is Vue code not pure HTML code

I will take the 1st group - the `time` example:

```
<div class="time_input" >
    <div class="time_input__radio_group">
        <div class="radio_group">
            <input type="radio" name="start" id="am" :value="true" v-model="startInMorning">
            <label class="radio_label" for="am">AM</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio_group">
            <input type="radio" name="start" id="pm" :value="false" v-model="startInMorning">
            <label class="radio_label" for="pm">PM</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both of `input`s is set to the same model `startInMorning` so if it is true both checked and vice versa.

So the fix is:

first remove the `v-model="startInMorning"` for both

next change the `:value`

for the first one `:value="startInMorning"`,
for the second one `:value="!startInMorning"`

Do similar for others

Comment: Hi sorry! I updated the thread for clarification - this is indeed a vue app. I nonetheless followed your suggestion and found the same problem occur (when I remove the additional CSS classes - the HTML works normal)

Comment: Figured out the solution! Updated original question