# How to change the color of the indicator showing the selected radiobutton in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 3 radiobuttons in the same group created in HTML as below.

[click to see radiobuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eddnu.png)

As you see, there is a little point on the left of "small" labelled radiobutton because it is the selected one. The color of that point is: `black`. I want to change it into `orange`. I've found changing the color of the text, background of the radiobutton etc. but how can I change the color of the point indicating which radiobutton is selected??

Solutions in css, js, jquery.. anything is ok.

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons) question. As mentioned there, it isn't possible.

However frameworks like Bootstrap will imitate the behavior of a radio button. With such a solution there are much more customization options. Watch [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/) for more details (scroll down to Radio Buttons).