# disabled and checked radio button design with black background

Tags: html, css, radio-button

On a webpage with black colour background, I have a couple of disabled radio buttons. One of them is checked. But, even though the radio button is checked the design is not clear to show that it is checked.

I know through CSS we can change the checked circle colour of the radio button. But is there any other standard way to make it look like checked and disabled as well?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the color of radio buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons)

Comment: Yes. This is one of the multiple ways to do it. I have seen so many other ways of doing it as well. But everything looks like a workaround to me. Is there no other standard way when everyone is moving toward the black theme nowadays?