# Radio button color change

Tags: css, radio-button

Using CSS how to change the radio button's default blue color to black or orange or any other color ?
Is there a way to achieve it without using custom radio buttons ?

```
<input id="rb_Gender" type="radio" name="rb_Gender" value=" " checked="checked">
```

[Existing Radio button with default blue color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1hna.png)

Comment: [Unfortunately no, Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons)

Comment: Hack using pseudo elements: https://www.codeply.com/go/NKtDpPXv2x